# Can anyone help me solve the following system of equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, surfaces, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have the following 4 equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
z &=& c_0 + c_1x + c_2y + c_3xy + c_4x^2 + c_5y^2 \\
2(x-x_0) &=& \lambda(c_1 + c_3y + 2c_4x) \\
2(y-y_0) &=& \lambda(c_2 + c_3x + 2c_5y) \\
2(z-z_0) &=& -\lambda
\end{eqnarray}

where $x, y, z$, and $\lambda$ are unknown, $c_i$ are known coefficients, and $x_0, y_0$, and $z_0$ are also known. Am I right in that this is a non-linear system of equations? Is there a way that I can solve this analytically? I'd prefer to not employ a numerical approach, if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is non-linear. Do $x_0,y_0$ and $z_0$ satisfy the same first relation?

Comment: @Bernard No! They don't. $\mathbf{x}_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point that lies off the surface described by the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a convenient change of coordinates like

$$
\cases{
x = \cos\theta X+\sin\theta Y\\
y = -\sin\theta x+\cos\theta Y\\
z = Z
}
$$

with a convenient $\theta$ we can reduce the system to

$$
\cases{Z=a_0+a_1 X+ a_2 Y + a_3 X^2+ a_4 Y^2\\
2(X-X_0)=\lambda(a_1+2a_3 X)\\
2(Y-Y_0)=\lambda(a_2+2a_4Y)\\
2(Z-Z_0) = -\lambda
}
$$

but even in this case, without previous knowledge of the involved parameters, the result is very lengthy. (As can be verified with the help of a symbolic processor like MATHEMATICA)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! It seems that this new system is also a non-linear equation. And my current challenge is solving this non-linear equation.